# OpenGL with Intel 82865G integrated graphics

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel, opengl

There's a similar question on the site, but it's outdated and doesn't specify exactly what I'm faced with. Namely, I have an old computer that I'm fixing for someone, and it's got this Intel 82865G integrated graphics controller. The problem is that it doesn't appear to handle any OpenGL things i throw at it.

For instance, glxgears returns this:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  28
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

And glxinfo returns the same.

The computer runs Ubuntu 12.04 in Unity 2D. The graphics card is capable of up to OpenGL 1.3 according to Intel, if that is at all relevant.

Comment: I think your question is subject to a bug-report - can you confirm? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1071530  looking into this, you need an updated mesa package - this is only available in the xorg-edgers PPA (take the stability issues seriously if you go down this route)

Comment: So, all you must do is type in that command? My computer gave the same bug as yours. I typed in sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core so must I now restart the machine?

Comment: Yes. That single installation command fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Installing xserver-xorg-core and rebooting destroys a freshly-installed 12.04's X. System boots to a black screen (with monitor on, not in power-save), though I can still ssh into the box, as I installed that beforehand.

Comment: @Mark S.: It did the same thing for me, but installing the package `xerver-xorg` made X work again, and what is more, OpenGL applications run now! Not only `glxgears`, but also [Tartini](http://externaldocumentation.blogspot.nl/2010/08/building-tartini-on-debian.html?showComment=1392160699431#c8258653979073841739), which was the reason I arrived here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link to that bug report, fossfreedom. I hadn't found it. The bug report doesn't state a direct answer, but the answer seems as simple as the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

OpenGL now works. It appears to be stuck in Unity 2D, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This package did destroy my X11 installation. To reinstall the following commands worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install openbox
sudo reboot
```

The installation of the OpenGL driver was in my case because of a non working XBMC installation. Now everything works.

Comment: What package destroyed your X11 installation?