# Ubuntu 12.04 runs in 2D only, has Intel 82865G graphics

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04 runs only in 2D Have an Intel 82865G Graphics Controller. Could this be the problem ? Went to the Intel download center, and this card is supposed to support 3D. It seems Ubuntu does not recocnize this card.

Comment: Similar or same question - OP confirms only works in 2D - http://askubuntu.com/questions/263550/opengl-with-intel-82865g-integrated-graphics?rq=1

Comment: Please add `sudo lspci | grep VGA` output to your question