# Is my CPU capable of running XBMC?

Tags: drivers

Is my CPU capable of running XBMC?

I am asking this because when on start up XBMC crashes and say something about Opengl and say need update.

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:feb80000-febfffff ioport:ed98(size=8)
```

Comment: Apparently you're not the only one to have XBMC crashes using the i915 video driver: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=129965

Can you confirm which Ubuntu version you're running and if you're using the XBMC build that comes with Ubuntu or if you're using one from a PPA?

Comment: Ya trusty tah 14.0.4 lts running ppa and tried the ubuntu way also idk whats up, im doing xbmcbuntu now and the desktop works fine but nit xbmc

Answer (score 2):

**XBMC Ubuntu Minimal Systems Requirements<sup>1</sup>**

- CPU: x86 or x86_64 processor such as: Intel Pentium 4, Intel Pentium M, AMD Athlon XP/64, AMD Opteron, or newer CPU. (Anything made in the last few years does.)
- RAM: 256MB minimum, 1GB recommended
- Graphics: XBMC will run on most graphics cards made in the last few years. This includes most cards from ATI/AMD, Intel, or NVIDIA which support OpenGL 2.0 or later.
- ATI/AMD - minimum: ATI Radeon RV710/M92 (HD 4300/4500), recommended: ATI Radeon Cedar (Radeon HD 5400 Series) or newer
- Intel - minimum: Intel GMA 950 (945G), recommended: Intel GMA X4500HD (G45) or newer
- Nvidia - minimum: Nvidia GeForce 6-Series, recommended: Nvidia GeForce 8-Series or newer
- Drive space: minimum: 4-8GB, recommended: 16GB or more

---

The Intel 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller is subject to this bug report: [X Error of failed request: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1071530). From the bug description: *My OpenGL has stopped working.* According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263550/opengl-with-intel-82865g-integrated-graphics/266562#266562) you can get OpenGL (by itself, not necessarily with XBMC) to work in Unity 2D with Intel 82865G Integrated Graphics by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>**Source:** [XBMCbuntu wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMCbuntu)</sub>